# Background image pixelated issues

Tags: html, css

I am using a circular image as a background image. But it is showing pixelated in the edges. How can I fix it?

[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
.icons.second_icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/mn-1.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<div class="icons  second_icon"></div>
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: what is the quality of the image? what is the file size? what kind of image is it?

Comment: Looks to me that it's the image that's at fault...

Comment: Its and png image. here is the link

Comment: So, couldn't you have made that clearer in your original question? You need to make your question clear - show what is your expected output and what is your actual output. We are good, but we are not *that* good to be able to tell where that image is coming from. That said; how on earth can we figure out the issue you're having if you haven't posted any code? We also don't know what you've tried, in order to resolve the issue. Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: Is the page you're trying to edit publicly accessible? Otherwise could we get a very minimal recreation of the issue.

Comment: i recreated your code in a snippet and see no pixellation. are you sure there aren't any other styles overriding the CSS you posted?

Answer (score 1):

You will note that your image actually is pixelated at the edges. Perhaps you need to use a different image or touch it up in an editing program?

[image]

Comment: Specifically im seeing pixelation on the right side.

Comment: Actually the image is not pixelated at all. you can check it in inspect element

Comment: Sorry to disagree, but there is definitely pixelation. See attached image :)

Comment: Don't worry, @BryantJackson - I don't even think the elders of the Internet would have known that the image originally posted wasn't the original, and what the OP is experiencing. I thought the same. Let's hope some code might reveal the mystery...